Firefox login on a particular website works ONLY when password has not been saved previously
I experience a strange behavior from Firefox 129.0.1 (Linux version, 64 bit), but it also occurred in previous versions. When I go to my banking website at blsk.de, there is a login for online banking. There you can enter an account name. And after that a new field for a pin/password occurs. At least it should. But when the account name is saved in the password manager of Firefox and you enter that in the first field the website won't show the second field for the pin/password anymore. It only works if the account name is not saved in the password manager. Do you have a clue what could be the root of this problem?
Best regards
M

Most likely a hidden field that is also saved that is like an anti-bot/anti-hack detection.

Not sure if the question belongs here, as it is really about the web-based service the bank offers.

@LPChip: Could you elaborate on this? Usually FF just saves user name and password. How does this involve a hidden form field?

If they add a hidden form field called password, and put something in it, your password manager will store it, and upon loading, reset it. The page then knows you are using a password manager and can stop a login.

Thank you very much. Could be that this is the case here.

Is there a way to hide a password manager from websites? So that they don't know.

Just to be sure about the root cause. Have you tried the same bank page in other browsers? Does Chrome/chromium browsers store the credentials?

@MDoe they don't know about any sort of password manager... You don't understand. The assumed prevention is that some field named password is filled by password software, which no matter which software it'd be, is done automatically as all password managers assume that name for a password field. Maybe some of them don't fill hidden fields, though.

@DanielPerez Yes, and the behavior is the same. Now I also noticed that when a password manager is in place, the account name field gets a different background shade.

@Destroy666 Yes, I think I understand what you mean. So, I'd need a password manager that does not fill in password fields automatically so that the javascript of the banking site would not recognize the password manager. This is so silly and such a paternalism towards the customer. Still, I have written to their support team and we will see what they reply. If they reply at all.
